# Reference book for Galois Representations

Tags: reference-request, galois-representations

I want to study about Galois Representation. All the books I have seen have titles like [some topic] and Galois Representation, where some topic=modular forms or automorphic forms. Is there any textbook or lecture notes which does not require automorphic forms or modular forms as a prerequisite (suited especially for beginners)?

Comment: Cross posted to [MathOverflow](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/247067/reference-book-for-galois-representations?noredirect=1&lq=1)